# size() causes error when switching from transform to filter

Tags: c++, std-ranges

When

- `views::filter([](auto n) { return n % 2 == 0; });` is activated, I fail to get `[2,4]`.
- `views::transform([](auto n) { return 2 * n; });` is activated, I succeed to get `[2,4,6,8,10]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto input = views::iota(1, 5 + 1);

    auto output = input |
                  views::filter([](auto n) { return n % 2 == 0; });
                  //views::transform([](auto n) { return 2 * n; });


    stringstream ss;
    ss << "[";
    for (auto i = 0; i < output.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        ss << output[i] << ',';
    }
    ss << output[output.size() - 1];
    ss << "]";
    cout << ss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the following error.

> Filtering.cpp:17:37: error: no matching function for call to 'std::ranges::filter_view<std::ranges::iota_view<int, int>, main()::<lambda(auto:17)> >::size()'
> 17 |     for (auto i = 0; i < output.size() - 1; ++i)

Comment: You cannot check `size()` of output nor can you access `output[i]`. `views::filter` doesn't permit it. Use range based for-loop or iterators instead.

Comment: If it is available, you could use [`std::experimental::ostream_joiner`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner)

Comment: In addition to what @ALX23z said: The `ranges::filter_view` is just a different class from `ranges::transform_view`. The latter one implements `size()` and `operator[]`. Keep in mind that these views are lazily evaluated - when you construct the `filter_view`, it does not know how many elements are there that fulfill your criterium.

Comment: Generally, you need to either add checks if it the first or last element. In case of `views::filter` it is difficult to tell if it is the last element, so replace it with first element check. Just print `value` for first element, and `,value` for all following elements.

Comment: You can simply use `<format>` like `cout << std::format("{}", output)`, the library has automatically handled this issue for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::ranges::filter_view` is not a "sized range", which means you can't call `size` on it. This is because the filtering is done on-demand, so asking for the size of the view would require consuming every element.

One option is to convert the view into a `std::vector` and use that. In C++20:

```
auto output_view = input
            | views::filter([](auto n) { return n % 2 == 0; }) 
            | views::transform([](auto n) { return 2 * n; });

std::vector<int> output(ranges::begin(output_view), ranges::end(output_view));
```

In C++23:

```
auto output = input
            | views::filter([](auto n) { return n % 2 == 0; }) 
            | views::transform([](auto n) { return 2 * n; })
            | ranges::to<std::vector>();
```

Another option is to make use of the fact that `filter_view` is a forward range so long as the underlying range is, so you can check if advancing the iterator hits the end:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "[";
auto it = ranges::begin(output);
for (; ranges::next(it) != ranges::end(output); ++it) {
    ss << *it << ',';
}
ss << *it;
ss << "]";
cout << ss.str();
```

Comment: I think it is better to print first element as `ss << *it;` and all following as `ss << ',' << *it` rather than performing awkward inefficient checks with `ranges::next(it)`.

Comment: `auto sep = ""; ss << "["; for (auto&& x : output) ss << exchange(sep, ",") << x; ss << "]";`  (Aside, I **loved** P0798, thank you thank you!)

Comment: The code in the answer would fail anyway if the range remains empty! Considering the comment before I'd rather go with `if(auto it = begin(); it != end() { ss << *it; for(++it; it != end(); ++it) { ss << ", " << *it; } }`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `vector` solution in the first place – this is just working around the usage of the inappropriate loop type, producing unnecessary memory overhead – and fails miserably for an unbounded range (while the correct loop at least potentially would instead iterate endlessly/until the programme is interrupted forcefully, which might in some other context be the intended behaviour).

Comment: Selectively omitting `std::` prefix? That may confuse some.

Answer (score 5):

A [`filter_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) is not a [`random_access_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/random_access_range) and it does not have a `size()` method. If you focus your attention on the exact error message that you showed that's what it says: there is no `size()`, anywhere in the vicinity.

You can think of it as analogous to a `std::forward_list`, instead of `std::vector`. You can use range iteration, instead:

```
    const char *sep="";
    for (const auto &n:output)
    {
        ss << sep << n;
        sep=",";
    }
```

Comment: [`std::list::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/size)?

Comment: We can even scope `sep` in the `for`: `for (auto * sep = ""; auto n : output)`

Comment: `forward_list` not `list`

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    auto input = views::iota(1, 5 + 1);

    auto output = input | views::filter([](const auto& n) {return n % 2 == 0; });

    stringstream ss;
    ss << "[";
    if (not ranges::empty(output))
    {
        ss << *ranges::begin(output);
        for (const auto &x : output | views::drop(1)) 
            ss << ',' << x;
    }
    ss << "]";
    cout << ss.str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fully agree on @Bob__ – though the test might remain commented out. This would illustrate that we don't need it in *this specific case* (output is guaranteed not to be empty), but in general we would.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist This is a C++ question, including foreign code is not useful (we don't even know if the question author is familiar with other languages), thus the rollback. Still acknowledging the intent.